# Clarification of Laravel Request Class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I see that laravel controller comes with 2 request class. Are they the same?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

and

```
use App\Http\Requests;
```

Is it optional to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

This one is a file located in [vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php) , it's a class with all the methods and properties related to a request, it extends SymfonyRequest.

```
class Request extends SymfonyRequest implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess
{
    // ...
}
```

---

```
use App\Http\Requests;
```

This one itself is just a namespace, it's like a stub to the requests namespace. I never use it (I use a line for every request).

It could be used in this way:

```
public function save(Requests\FormRequest $request)
```

Answer (score 1):

`App\Http\Requests\Request` extends the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` and any class that extends it is going to validate itself when resolved out of the IoC Container.

On the other hand `Illuminate\Http\Request` is just a plain request that extends directly from `SymfonyRequest` it's useful to inject in your controller methods if you just need to extract the request parameters or the user from the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 (I hope :p) you can just use at the top:

```
use Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure about use Illuminate\Http\Request;
But App\Http\Request is the class which is used to:

1. Get users' input data.

If user fills form, then we can get data with the help of this class.

2.Make user input validations.

Validations can be done in controller but it is not good practice.
We should use seperate request class that can be made by:
php artisan make:request request-class-name.
This will make a file in App\Http\Requests\ with given name i.e. request-class-name.
In this class we can do validations as well as authorizations.
If you want to learn about authorizations then learn about Gates https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization.